# Configure nginx-ingress for Azure Kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, azure-aks

I have been trying to find information on how to best configure the ingress service for Kubernetes since we are seeing a lot of restarts (during performance testing) of the pods which then eventually end up in a crash loop.

I can't find any information on how to set the worker_process and what that value should be compared to the number of cores and ingress pods we are running.
When I had a 4 vCore VM the worker_process was 4 and when I changed to a 16 vCore VM the worker_process changed to 16, so I guess by default it is taking the value of the VM, is this a ok value?

When I set auto scale I get  for "TARGETS" and I can't see it scale when going above the 50% threshold:

```
NAME                          REFERENCE                              TARGETS                        MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
my-nginx-ingress-controller   Deployment/my-nginx-ingress-controller <unknown>/50%, <unknown>/50%   2         12        6          2d
```

I have set this in my conf:

```
autoscaling:
enabled: true
minReplicas: 2
maxReplicas: 12
targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 50
targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage: 50
```

When I increase the number of replicas for the ingress I get less restarts, but they also eat a lot of CPU looking in the dashboard, so I would prefer to have less.

What do I need to change to get a god setup, please let me know if I should add any more information.

**EDIT**

I can see this in the log dumps I have, the time for all of these type of entries match the pod restart graph.

Logs

```
I0719 12:49:35.255169       8 leaderelection.go:187] attempting to acquire leader lease  kube-system/ingress-controller-leader-nginx...
I0719 12:49:35.255314       8 nginx.go:279] Starting NGINX process
I0719 12:49:35.257764       8 controller.go:172] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required.
I0719 12:49:35.328405       8 leaderelection.go:196] successfully acquired lease kube-system/ingress-controller-leader-nginx
I0719 12:49:35.328744       8 status.go:148] new leader elected: xyz-nginx-ingress-controller-7d8c4474cb-xpg7c
I0719 12:49:35.599587       8 controller.go:190] Backend successfully reloaded.
I0719 12:49:35.599884       8 controller.go:202] Initial sync, sleeping for 1 second.
```

Query

```
KubePodInventory
| where Namespace == "kube-system"
| where ServiceName contains "ingress"
| summarize count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 10m), Name, PodRestartCount
| render timechart
```

[image]

Comment: what is causing the restarts? You should be able to see what is causing the pods to crash from the container logs. Since the restarts are less frequent when you scale up, this is likely a resource exhaustion issue with the pods. More pods mean less workload per pod

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to find that information, I have dumped the logs using PowerShell and can see a lot of entries which contain this message, "Starting NGINX process", but there is no ID's mentioned. I also can't seem to figure out where in the Azure monitor logs I can see messages from a specific pod. I have managed to get a graph of the restarts per pod, so I know which ID's the restarting pods have.
Do you have any idea which log index I need to search in to find the reason for the restarts?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how Azure handles logs. Since you know the ID of pods that restart frequently, try to monitor the logs of the nginx container for that pod (`kubectl logs [pod_name]`) until it crashes. Hopefully, that will show the nginx container exiting along with the exit status. You can also describe the nginx ingress pod and check the last exit status, that might help as well.

Comment: I suspect this might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/4041) due to the `Configuration changes detected, backend reload required.` message

Comment: Can you share the result of executing `kubectl describe pod [pod_name]` after it crashes? on the event section you can si if the problem is related to a resource exhaustion and kubelet is forcing the restart

Comment: Ok, I will have a look at the events for a crashing pod during the next test run.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I think we found the issue for the high CPU and restarting pods. It was most likely a faulty setup in our test suite that didn't use keep-alive correctly, so we overloaded the Ingress with to many SSL handshakes. Still not a answer to my initial question about the auto-scaling, but now we don't really need it anymore since the performance with the correct keep-alive setup does not take so much CPU anymore.